# SQL Server Stored Procedure takes long time to execute

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm still new to SQL. I made a stored procedure with some looping inside. I want to make a stored procedure with few parameters in Delphi.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_operator6]
    @awal DATETIME,
    @akhir DATETIME,
    @pumpsMotor VARCHAR(500),
    @pumpsMobil VARCHAR(500),
    @pumpsSolar VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tbl_pumpMotor TABLE (pumpnumber INT)

    INSERT INTO @tbl_pumpMotor 
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.SplitList(@pumpsMotor,',')

    DECLARE @tbl_pumpMobil TABLE (pumpnumber INT)

    INSERT INTO @tbl_pumpMobil 
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.SplitList(@pumpsMobil,',')

    DECLARE @tbl_pumpSolar TABLE (pumpnumber INT)

    INSERT INTO @tbl_pumpSolar 
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.SplitList(@pumpsSolar,',')

    DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @tbl_result TABLE (Nama VARCHAR(MAX),
                               [shift 1 Motor] INT, 
                               [shift 2 Motor] INT, 
                               [shift 3 Motor] INT,
                               [shift 1 Mobil] INT, 
                               [shift 2 Mobil] INT, 
                               [shift 3 Mobil] INT,
                               [shift 1 Solar] INT, 
                               [shift 2 Solar] INT, 
                               [shift 3 Solar] INT)

    DECLARE @tbl_shift1 TABLE (shiftid INT)

    INSERT INTO @tbl_shift1 
        SELECT [id] 
        FROM [shift] 
        WHERE bizdate BETWEEN @awal AND @akhir 
          AND shiftworkdayid = 1

   declare @tbl_shift2 table (shiftid int)
insert into @tbl_shift2 select [id] from [shift] where bizdate between @awal and @akhir and shiftworkdayid=2

declare @tbl_shift3 table (shiftid int)
insert into @tbl_shift3 select [id] from [shift] where bizdate between @awal and @akhir and shiftworkdayid=3

declare hk_cursor cursor for
select distinct  operatorname from [transaction] where [date] between @awal and @akhir and OperatorName<>'RFID'

OPEN hk_cursor
fetch next from hk_cursor into @var2

while (@@fetch_status=0)
BEGIN
insert into @tbl_result
select operator.nama, 
shift1Motor.[shift 1 Motor], shift2Motor.[shift 2 Motor], shift3Motor.[shift 3 Motor],
shift1Mobil.[shift 1 Mobil], shift2Mobil.[shift 2 MoBIL], shift3Mobil.[shift 3 MoBIL],
shift1SOLAR.[shift 1 SOLAR], shift2SOLAR.[shift 2 SOLAR], shift3SOLAR.[shift 3 SOLAR]
from

  (select top 1 operatorname as Nama from [Transaction] where operatorname=@var2) as operator,
-- ====================================== MOTOR
  (SELECT count (distinct [ShiftId]) as [shift 1 Motor]  
  FROM [Transaction] 
  where 
  [date] between @awal and @akhir
  and operatorname = @var2
  and pumpnumber in ( select pumpnumber from @tbl_pumpMotor)
  and shiftid in (select shiftid from @tbl_shift1)
  )
  as shift1Motor,

(SELECT count (distinct 
      [ShiftId])
      as [shift 2 Motor]

  FROM [Transaction]
  where 
  [date] between @awal and @akhir
  and operatorname = @var2
  and pumpnumber in ( select pumpnumber from @tbl_pumpMotor)
  and shiftid in (select shiftid from @tbl_shift2)
 ) 
  as shift2Motor,

  (SELECT count (distinct [ShiftId])as [shift 3 Motor]
  FROM [Transaction]
  where 
  [date] between @awal and @akhir
  and operatorname = @var2
  and pumpnumber in ( select pumpnumber from @tbl_pumpMotor)
  and shiftid in (select shiftid from @tbl_shift3)
 ) 
  as shift3Motor,

-- ====================================== MOBIL

(SELECT count (distinct [ShiftId]) as [shift 1 MoBIL]
FROM [Transaction] 
  where 
  [date] between @awal and @akhir
  and operatorname = @var2
  and pumpnumber in ( select pumpnumber from @tbl_pumpMobil)
  and shiftid in (select shiftid from @tbl_shift1)
  )
as shift1Mobil,

(SELECT count (distinct [ShiftId])as [shift 2 MoBIL] 
FROM [Transaction]
  where 
  [date] between @awal and @akhir
  and operatorname =@var2
 and pumpnumber in ( select pumpnumber from @tbl_pumpMobil)
  and shiftid in (select shiftid from @tbl_shift2)
 ) 
  as shift2Mobil,

  (SELECT count (distinct [ShiftId])as [shift 3 MoBIL]
  FROM [Transaction] 
  where 
  [date] between @awal and @akhir
  and operatorname = @var2
  and pumpnumber in ( select pumpnumber from @tbl_pumpMobil)
  and shiftid in (select shiftid from @tbl_shift3)
 ) 
  as shift3Mobil,

  -- ====================================== SOLAR

  (SELECT count (distinct [ShiftId]) as [shift 1 SOLAR]   
 FROM [Transaction]
  where 
  [date] between @awal and @akhir
  and operatorname = @var2
  and pumpnumber in ( select pumpnumber from @tbl_pumpSolar)
  and shiftid in (select shiftid from @tbl_shift1)
  )
as shift1SOLAR,

(SELECT count (distinct [ShiftId]) as [shift 2 SOLAR]
  FROM [Transaction] 
  where 
  [date] between @awal and @akhir
  and operatorname = @var2
  and pumpnumber in ( select pumpnumber from @tbl_pumpSolar)
  and shiftid in (select shiftid from @tbl_shift2)
 ) 
  as shift2SOLAR,

  (SELECT count (distinct [ShiftId]) as [shift 3 SOLAR]
  FROM [Transaction] 
  where 
  [date] between @awal and @akhir
  and operatorname = @var2
  and pumpnumber in ( select pumpnumber from @tbl_pumpSolar)
  and shiftid in (select shiftid from @tbl_shift3)
 ) 
  as shift3SOLAR
FETCH NEXT from hk_cursor into @var2
END

close hk_cursor
deallocate hk_cursor

select * from @tbl_result
end
```

and here how i execute

```
execute sp_operator6 '2015-8-10','2015-8-15','4,3,33,34,35,36','5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22','23,24,27,28,31,32'
```

It took 7 minutes to execute with result 25 records in local server. 
Is there any way to write this stored procedure any simpler than this way?
Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks,  will avoid that sp_.

Comment: Let's start with your splitter. What does it look like? Does it have loops? Your procedure code is very problematic. It reads like a dotnet application, not data retrieval. Loops and cursors should be avoided whenever possible. Then your main query is a whole pile of individual select statements. This whole process needs a total overhaul. It could be simplified to a single insert statement without loops and dozens of queries. I would even suggest your delimited lists could become table valued parameters and avoid splitting.

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(`right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics)` and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: Another thing... Avoid the use of table variables when you expect to be inserting more than a few rows. Use temp tables instead. The difference is that SQL Server builds statics for temp table but not for table variables (it simply assumes a single row)... This difference can have a very real impact on the resulting execution plan.

Comment: And you can index table variables.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I decided to change the query. i avoid the looping. I make the looping inside the program, not in the query. It takes 2 minutes. I'm not satisfied, but for now this is the solution. Thanks everybody, i'll learn deeper..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to start thinking in terms of sets and avoid looping especially unneeded looping.

Next you have a giant cross join, that is usually not good for performance.

If you have more than few records in those table variables then ditch them and use temp tables instead and then index them.

Consider adding a type column to the table variable (or temp table) and putting all the info into one table. This might make it simpler to aggregate using a case statement. A pivot query might also be useful.

You also need to look at your Execution plans, you might be missing some indexes that would be useful.

Comment: Thanks HLGEM, as you said, i avoid looping, so i make the looping inside the program. It makes the query faster.